# PHP text scanner how?

Tags: php

I want to make a text scanner for similar words in PHP, but I do not know where to begin. The scanner will have to scan a paragraph and point out matches that are found in a Database or propose specific words that will assist in making this paragraph better.

I thought at first that I could use a database and a search engine script but I have been told that this is not the way to do it.

Can someone please point me to the right direction so I can start working on this?

Comment: similar in word (e.g. carry, carrier, carrying) or similar in meaning (e.g. car, vehicle, transport)?

Comment: similar as car, vehicle, transport

Comment: So you are looking for a synonims search engine?

Comment: thats what i thought i should work on at first.. a Search engine script.. and i did.. but i was told that instead of a search engine i should use some kind of parser.. is that correct? how can i make such a parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just post another answer because my first one was wrong after the OP comment and it had too many comments.

First you need to extrapolate every single word from your paragraph, using for example:

```
$words_array = explode(" ", $paragraph);
```

Then you need to remove special characters, slashes, points, commas etc. (maybe using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)).

In the second step you need to build a Database of synonyms like this:

```
| id | word | synonyms |
| 0  | car  | vehicle  |
| 1  | car  | transport |
```

Then do something like (for each word of your paragraph):

```
SELECT synonyms FROM table WHERE word="car"
```

And after this you can fetch the results.

But **this is only the start**. You **NEED** to optimize this method. Example: you can do that when you search vehicle it returns car. The same for transport. That's up to you!

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierpaolo. That concept seems to do the trick.. I'll give it a go!

Comment: unfortunately i can not vote up this suggestion as my reputation points are below 15.. but +1 on this one! Thank you!

Comment: A simple text-*scanner* can be build with [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), the manual as an example how to split a string at spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for similarities in text can be real hard work. 
If you want to search the paragraph and then check if there's a similar text in the database I would advise to use the "[tfidf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf)" algorithm. I used it in my thesis and it did worked fine.

However there is no "master" algorithm that does everything you need. It's a lot of research and it always depends on the properties of the text you'll use.
Some knowledge about [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) could also help solving such problems.

For finding only word similarites I would use something like [this](http://nlp.cic.ipn.mx/publications/2006/rcs-2006-morphology.pdf).
Hope his helps.

Comment: this is interesting.. i'll have to go through your suggestions.. Thanks for the input..

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)? It's very easy to use and you can easily adaptate it to using a DB (where DB may be a text file, a SQL DB or even an Array).

Fast example:

```
// you have to call this function multiple times for each word of the paragraph and for each word of your DB of suggestions
function suggest ($word_of_the_paragraph, $word_taken_from_a_DB) {
    similar_text($word_of_the_paragraph, $word_taken_from_a_DB, $percent);
    if ($percent >= $threshold) {
        echo $word_taken_from_a_DB; // this is the suggested word
    }
}
```

Comment: Quoted from PHP Docs: `This calculates the similarity between two strings`, notice the "**two**". The OP's question is about finding similar words in the same string. Your answer doesn't provide any information that can be helpful regarding the subject. Thus, down voted. And frankly I find it odd that someone upvoted it, just because I down voted it doesn't mean I'm evil or I hate you. This is just how this community (SO) work.

Comment: I still don't understand. You can scan every single word of the paragraph and compare it multiple times with a database (text file, array, MySQL or something). Then you can handle it like the way I posted (I have edited my post).

Comment: I was told that the correct way would be by using some kind of parser.. I have no idea really.. i'm confused..

Comment: @PierpaoloBagnasco, now that you edited your answer things look a bit different. I honestly now wish I can upvote it two times, one because of the answer itself and one because you handled criticism pretty well. Respect.

Comment: Well, my answer refers only to the "similarity problem"... Of course you need a parser first that scans every single word of the paragraph and then calls my function. Basically you need to "build" the two variables $word_of_the_paragraph and $word_taken_from_a_DB. The parser obviously varies depending on the paragraph format.

Comment: @AdnanShammout No problem :)
Ehm, I read OP comment: "similar as car, vehicle, transport". So my function is useless in this case.

Comment: sorry.. :) i am still not sure what exactly i need.. i've been left alone to figure it out and i cant think anything else rather than your script or the one below..